# How to test User Interface in Swift Package

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I have a question about making a Swift Package.

I have written some User Interface code in a single page Xcode project. My goal is to migrate the  UI code over to a SwiftPackage so that I can use it interchangeably in different Xcode projects. The problem is I don't want to update the user interface code in the swift package every time something goes wrong in another Xcode project. I just want to run the User Interface code in the swift package and see it. Is there a way I can do that?